# Can't find Microsoft.Cpp folder

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have development environment where everything work pretty well.
Now I want to build my project on dedicated server via TFS Build. I set up controller, agent and installed MSBuild from there - [Microsoft Build Tools 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760). Now when I run my build I receive next error "*The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.*". It is really absent on disk, but I installed before MSBuild and Visual C++ Redistributable as well.

What should I install to have this folder in my MSBuild? I'm pretty sure that installation of VS Express isn't good solution.

Comment: The download page is pretty explicit about it: "for building *managed* applications".  If you want to build C++ projects then you need to install VS.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank for your answer.  Do I get correct? I need to install entire Visual Studio instance (at least C++ express) on my build server for building there Visual C++ project? And no way to install any moderate package?

Comment: @HansPassant could it be that Windows SDK is enough?